# Retrieving information from a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am currently facing a dilemma within the project I am currently completing. I have a database where two tables are linked through foreign keys which are of data type int.

What I am trying to do is retrieve a value from `tblProductColour` and using the `INNER JOIN` function add the information to the other table which is `tblProducts`.

Here is the controller code,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var db = WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open("Database");

        if (Session["AdministrationTeam"] != null)
        {
            View = "ViewAllProducts";
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }

        return View(View, odb.tblproducts.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM tblproducts t INNER JOIN tblProductColour ot ON t.ID = ot.ProductColour"));
}
```

The getters and setters that are stored within the model itself are as shown below,

```
public int? ProductColour {get;set;}
```

Here is the code I am using in my View to retrieve the information from the model,

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
            <img src="@item.ProductImagePath" alt="Image Should Show Here" style="margin:auto auto; background-color:#fff;" width="100%" height="20%"/>
                <p>Product Id: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id) </p>

                <p> Product Name: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</p>

                <p>Supplier: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductSupplier) </p>

                <p>Colour: @Html.DisplayFor(modelIteem => item.ProductColour) </p>

            <p>Product Quantity: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductQuantity)</p>      

            <p> Product Description: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)</p>
    </div>
```

When retrieving the information, I am faced with this error shown below,

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Red' to data type int.

Here are the entities,
[tblproducts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAqAq.png)
[tblProductColour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HGVg.png)
If anyone has any solutions to how I can display the information it would be appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply i am using Sql Server within MVC razor (C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining the wrong items

```
"SELECT * FROM tblproducts t INNER JOIN tblProductColour ot ON t.ID = ot.ProductColour"
```

should be

```
"SELECT * FROM tblproducts t INNER JOIN tblProductColour ot ON t.ProductColour = ot.ID"
```

You then need to change

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelIteem => item.ProductColour)`

in your view to (assuming the correct reference name for the table is `tblProductColours`) to

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelIteem => item.tblProductColours.ProductColour)` 
- or 
`@Html.DisplayFor(modelIteem => item.ProductColours.ProductColour)` -

may also work - just depends on how it is referenced, hopefully autocomplete will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for you answer But it is only displaying a numeric value aka the id of the other table instead of the data stored into column ProductColour

Comment: Without using the sql correction I gave you your code will never work. You should be able to replace `item.ProductColour` with `item.tblProductColours.ProductColour` to get the colour name - that's assuming the table is referenced as `tblProductColours`.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help that has resolved the issue.